# Water ripple - The image cannot load on first time

Tags: javascript, html, ripple

I follow the instructions to create water ripple effects, I replaced the background by my image. The effect run pretty good. But it have a problem. When load it first time, the browser cannot load my background (my image), you have to reload browser (F5) or enter again on address bar to see the effect. How to solve it?

My Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Water Ripple HTML5</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Brent Dingle">
    <meta name="description" content="HTML5 canvas example of water ripple effect">

    <style >
        .waterCanvasStyle
        {
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color:#a1a1d0;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: #c6c6d0 4px 4px 10px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="waterCanvas0" width="400" height="400" >
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas      = document.getElementById('waterCanvas0');
        var ctx         = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var width       = canvas.width;
        var height      = canvas.height;
        var halfWidth   = width  >> 1;
        var halfHeight  = height >> 1;
        var size        = width * (height + 2) * 2;   // space for 2 images (old and new), +2 to cover ripple radius <= 3
        var delay       = 30;                                  // delay is desired FPS
        var oldIdx      = width;
        var newIdx      = width * (height + 3);       // +2 from above size calc +1 more to get to 2nd image
        var rippleRad   = 3;

        var rippleMap   = [];
        var lastMap     = [];
        var mapIdx;
        
        // texture and ripple will hold the image data to be displayed
        var ripple;
        var texture;
        
        // Any image can be used, but we will create a simple pattern instead
        // So need some variables to create the background/underwater image
        var stripeWidth = 25;
        var step        = stripeWidth * 2;
        var count       = height / stripeWidth;
        
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "sea.jpg"; 
               
        // Here is a neat trick so you don't have to type ctx.blah over and over again
        with (ctx)
        {
            drawImage(img,0,0); 
            save();
            restore();
        }
        
        // Initialize the texture and ripple image data
        // Texture will never be changed
        // Ripple is what will be altered and displayed --> see run() function
        texture = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
        ripple = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
        
        // Initialize the maps
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lastMap[i]   = 0;
            rippleMap[i] = 0;
        }
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // --------------------- Main Run Loop --------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        function run()
        {
            newframe();
            ctx.putImageData(ripple, 0, 0);
        }
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Drop something in the water at location: dx, dy
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        function dropAt(dx, dy)
        {
            // Make certain dx and dy are integers
            // Shifting left 0 is slightly faster than parseInt and math.* (or used to be)
            dx <<= 0;
            dy <<= 0;
            
            // Our ripple effect area is actually a square, not a circle
            for (var j = dy - rippleRad; j < dy + rippleRad; j++)
            {
                for (var k = dx - rippleRad; k < dx + rippleRad; k++)
                {
                    rippleMap[oldIdx + (j * width) + k] += 512;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Create the next frame of the ripple effect
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        function newframe()
        {
            var i;
            var a, b;
            var data, oldData;
            var curPixel, newPixel;
            
            // Store indexes - old and new may be misleading/confusing
            //               - current and next is slightly more accurate
            //               - previous and current may also help in thinking
            i = oldIdx;
            oldIdx = newIdx;
            newIdx = i;
            
            // Initialize the looping values - each will be incremented
            i = 0;
            mapIdx = oldIdx;
            
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // Use rippleMap to set data value, mapIdx = oldIdx
                    // Use averaged values of pixels: above, below, left and right of current
                    data = (
                            rippleMap[mapIdx - width] + 
                            rippleMap[mapIdx + width] + 
                            rippleMap[mapIdx - 1] + 
                            rippleMap[mapIdx + 1]) >> 1;    // right shift 1 is same as divide by 2
                    
                    // Subtract 'previous' value (we are about to overwrite rippleMap[newIdx+i])
                    data -= rippleMap[newIdx + i];
   
                    // Reduce value more -- for damping
                    // data = data - (data / 32)
                    data -= data >> 5;
   
                    // Set new value
                    rippleMap[newIdx + i] = data;

                    // If data = 0 then water is flat/still,
                    // If data > 0 then water has a wave
                    data = 1024 - data;
        
                    oldData = lastMap[i];
                    lastMap[i] = data;
        
                    if (oldData != data)  // if no change no need to alter image
                    {
                        // Recall using "<< 0" forces integer value
                        // Calculate pixel offsets
                        a = (((x - halfWidth) * data / 1024) << 0) + halfWidth;
                        b = (((y - halfHeight) * data / 1024) << 0) + halfHeight;
                        
                        // Don't go outside the image (i.e. boundary check)
                        if (a >= width) a = width - 1;
                        if (a < 0) a = 0;
                        if (b >= height) b = height - 1;
                        if (b < 0) b = 0;

                        // Set indexes
                        newPixel = (a + (b * width)) * 4;
                        curPixel = i * 4;
                        
                        // Apply values
                        ripple.data[curPixel]       = texture.data[newPixel];
                        ripple.data[curPixel + 1] = texture.data[newPixel + 1];
                        ripple.data[curPixel + 2] = texture.data[newPixel + 2];
                    }
                    mapIdx++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Select random location to create drops
        // So if user is doing nothing, water still
        // gets ripples.
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        function randomDrop()
        {
           // Make it a little, irregular in timing
           if ( Math.random() > 0.3 )
           {
                dropAt(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);
           }
        }
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Event handler for mouse motion
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        canvas.onmousemove = function(/* Event */ evt)
        {
            dropAt(evt.offsetX || evt.layerX, evt.offsetY || evt.layerY);
        }
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Begin our infinite loop
        // For user interaction and display updates
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        setInterval(run, delay);
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // Create random ripples
        // Note: this is NOT at same rate as display refresh
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        setInterval(randomDrop, 1250);
        
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common error when this type of issue occurs, is that you are trying to draw the image before it loads. Try utilizing the `img.onload` function to wait until the image has loaded to do all of the drawing and then to start running the main loop.